# Conditionally add .trim modifier in Vue.js Input field

Tags: vue.js, access-modifiers, v-model

How can we add .trim modifier with v-model conditionally?
Creating a global input field for the entire application, some fields need to be trim others not. Making an input for this (isTrim ) in the component.

```
<input v-model.trim="msg">
```

Can we add conditionally above trim with the component input?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can. I can however suggest a convenient computed property:

```html
<input v-model="valueThatNeedsTrim" />
```

```js
data() {
  return {
    valueFromData: "",
  }
},

computed() {
  valueThatNeedsTrim: {
    get() {
      return this.valueFromData
    },
    set(value) {
      this.valueFromData = value.trim()
    }
  }
}
```